# React hooks from does not set the value using setValue()

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have  combo box like this. I use thos module as the comboBox
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-combo-box

```
 const { register, setValue } = useForm();

<ComboBox
     options={options}
     name={"combo"}
     optionsListMaxHeight={200}
     enableAutocomplete
     className="contractComboBox"
     ref={register("combo")}
     onBlur={(evt) => comboBoxOnSelect(evt, "combo")}
  />
```

I am trying to set the value using set value in the onBlur function

```
const comboBoxOnSelect = (evt, item) => {
    setValue(item, evt.target.value)
}
```

but I cannot see the value under getValues() of react hooks form. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: it should be this i guess. ```setValue("combo", evt.target.value) ``` Do you have to pass evt.target.value as a string?

Comment: Hey – is it possible to get the full context of how your code is structured so we can reproduce exactly what's happening? I think seeing inside `useForm` and `comboBoxOnSelect` may help some.

Comment: I will add comboBoxOnSelect to the code

Comment: @RaviTheja I corrected the code it was a mistke when posting here. I havent pass it as a string

Comment: @DamilareOlusakin code is updated

Comment: Looks like your `event.target.value` might be empty if the user blurs this without first selecting an option. Have you tried selecting an option then opening the list and blurring it just to rule out that probable cause?

Comment: @DamilareOlusakinI havent tried that but i have loged the evt,traget.value always and there always a value

Comment: Okay, trying to fire up a mini playground on my machine to help debug this

Comment: @DamilareOlusakin Thanks.. I am also trying different methods..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231876/discussion-between-damilare-olusakin-and-samz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a small piece for you, looks like the problem is what I suspected, there is no "default value" for when a user opens the drop-down, and closes it without selecting a value. However, if you hard code a value in the `setValue` call, you'll find that the `comboOnSelect` and `setValue` work as expected. The issue is you need to find a way to set a default value.

**Initial test to find the issue:**

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import ComboBox from "react-responsive-combo-box";
import "react-responsive-combo-box/dist/index.css";


function App() {
  const { register, setValue, getValues } = useForm();

  const comboBoxOnSelect = (evt, item) => {
    setValue(item, "evt.target.value");
    console.log(evt.target.value);
    console.log(getValues());
  };

  const options = [
    "America",
    "India",
    "Australia",
    "Argentina",
    "Ireland",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iceland",
    "Japan",
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComboBox
        options={options}
        name={"combo"}
        optionsListMaxHeight={200}
        enableAutocomplete
        className="contractComboBox"
        {...register("combo")}
        onBlur={(evt) => comboBoxOnSelect(evt, "combo")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Solution**
Give `ComboBox` a default value prop

```
<ComboBox
  options={options}
  name={"combo"}
  optionsListMaxHeight={200}
  enableAutocomplete
  defaultValue={'America'}
  className="contractComboBox"
  {...register("combo")}
  onBlur={(evt) => comboBoxOnSelect(evt, "combo")}
/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. But seems something else is wrong i tried this and i tried hard coding the values. still its not setting with getValues(). I am wondering where its going wrong.

Comment: Let's move this to a discussion room? Already left you some messages

Comment: Hi sure.. One of the guy says its because of my combo box and it cannot register in react hook forms

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass mode as `onBlur` to your comboBox component.
[Here](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#useForm) you can check all the available modes of react-hook-form.

With the help of `react-hook-form`'s  `<Controller/>` component, we can use external controlled components.

You can check more on this here [Controller Component](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#Controller).

```
const { register, setValue, control } = useForm({
 mode: "onBlur",
 });
 
 <Controller
  as={
     <ComboBox
       options={options}
       optionsListMaxHeight={200}
       enableAutocomplete
       className="contractComboBox"
     />
   }
   control={control}
   name="combo"
 />;
```

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Hi thnks you..  but I cannot import the controller 
Attempted import error: 'Controller' is not exported from 'react-hook-form'.

Comment: You can import it like this
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

BTW which version are you using?

Comment: Thats the way i imported it. 
import  { useForm,  FormContext ,Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

maybe a version issue?

Comment: The version is "react-hook-form": "3.29.4",

Comment: The controller is supported from v5 as per official doc.

Comment: This file include many other use of react forms will updating it may be course a problem?

Comment: I think it will break other functionalities.

Comment: Yeah me too So i will not do that. do u see any other solution to add this to the values of the form?

Comment: Lemme set up the playground. Will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231875/discussion-between-samz-and-shubham-jajoo).